# similar formats for multiple variables before merging

Tags: merge

I have 4 datasets and used " colnames" function to make them all similar but merging function does not work beacuse the format of some varibales differ among dataset eventhough the names are the same.

````
 ``` colnames(f22)<- colnames(f21)   
  colnames(f23)<- colnames(f21)  
  colnames(f24)<- colnames(f21)   
  ef_all<-   bind_rows (list (f21,f22,f23,f24), .id="ef_number")```
````

````
# Error
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `1$ef_Indicator` <character> and `2$ef_Indicator` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I tried to use the folowing argument  but since there are around 300 varibles , it takes time to convert formats one by one before mering :

  ``` f21$ef_Indicator<- as.character(f21$ef_Indicator)
   f22$ef_Indicator<- as.character(f22$ef_Indicator)
   f23$ef_Indicator<- as.character(f23$ef_Indicator)
   f24$ef_Indicator<- as.character(f24$ef_Indicator) ```

# New error
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `1$ef_formul` <character> and `2$ef_formul` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
````

Is there any way to make a consistent format for common varibles before merging ?

As explained I tried